# Find substring in json's value and return the field

Tags: python, json

I've got a nested json and I would like to find a substring in any pair's value. The results should be the pair's name or None or similar if not found at all. So for example let's assume that I am looking for the substring `"met"`. Then for:

```
{
  "a": "example",
  {
     "b": "another example",
     "c": "something else"
  }
}
```

result should be `"c"` (as `"met"` is found in `"something else"`)
and for:

```
{
 "a": "example",
 {
    "b": "another example",
    "c": "yet another one"
 }
}
```

the result should be `None` as no `met` is found.

I have no additional information about json.

How to do it in the most efficient way?

Comment: Your json has illegal syntax, that inner dict has no key

Comment: Quite a few other answers searching with `python find a string in a value in a nested dictionary site:stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a recursive function to check each of the values and return the key for the first match

```
def find_nested(item, d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            return find_nested(item, value)
        if item in value:
            return key
```

For example

```
>>> d = {
  "a": "example",
  "d": {
     "b": "another example",
     "c": "something else"
  }
}
>>> find_nested('met', d)
'c'

>>> d = {
  "a": "example",
  "d": {
     "b": "another example",
     "c": "yet another one"
  }
}
>>> find_nested('met', d)  # returns None
```